# Search select statement

Tags: sql, search-engine

I am creating a page which would have different field for the user to search from.
e.g. search by:

- Grade: -dropdownlist1-
- Student name: -dropdownlist2-
- Student ID: -dropdownlist3-
- Lessons: -dropdownlist4-
- Year: -dropdownlist5-

How do I write the select statement for this? Each dropdownlist would need a select statement which would extract out different data from the database.

But, I want to write ONE select statement which can dynamically choose the dropdownlist options. Instead of writing many many select statement.

Lets say;

- Grade: -dropdownlist1- ; default value(all)
- Student name: -dropdownlist2-; default value(all)
- Student ID: -dropdownlist3-; 0-100 is choosen
- Lessons: -dropdownlist4-; A-C is choosen
- Year: -dropdownlist5-; 2009 is choosen

Comment: Are you asking how to fill the select lists or how to query your database given certain selected values? What database engine are you using (e.g. Mysql, Sql Server, Oracle, etc.)?

Comment: how to query the database i think. 
I need to write ONE sql statement to call out the data from 2 different tables.
I am using C# and the database engine is Sql Server.

Comment: By doing like this, am i doing it right?
If its wrong, how do i correct it?

select * from Students where (@Grade = 'All' or Grade = @Grade) and (@StudentName = 'All' or StudentName = @StudentName) and (StudentID = 'All' or StudentID = @StudentID) + 
inner join select * from Subject where (@Lessons = 'All' or Lessons = @Lessons) and (@Year = 'All' or Year = @Year);

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language you're using between SQL and the page.  But test the dropdown for a non-generic value and then add in a where clause:

```
sql = "select * from people where 1 = 1";
if(dropdownlist.value != "All")
  sql += "and name like '%" + dropdownlist.value + "%' ";
```

(watch out for SQL Injection though)

Comment: what if my table is not only from 1 table. but it is from several tables? I am using C#.

Answer (score 0):

Extending to Tom's answer,

Create a view first which will contain the needed record set. Query on the view.